# How to view Iterable events sent to Datadog through segment

Tags: datadog

I'm using Iterable, Segment, and Datadog in my mobile app. Iterable is used to send out marketing campaigns, Segment is used to send events and connects sources to destinations, and Datadog is used to aggregate logs, filter logs, and create monitors from metrics. My end goal is to create a Datadog monitor to monitor the deliverability and number of messages sent from Iterable. Iterable is a source in my segment app, and I've specified Datadog as a destination for Iterable. When I go into the debugger for Iterable, I see tons of events like below.

[image: iterable-sources]

In the Datadog destination tab on segment, in the "Event Delivery" tab I see events being delivered.

[image: iterable-events-to-datadog]

How can I view these Iterable events in Datadog? I need to be able to see these events in datadog in order to create a monitor tracking these events.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote one of the Datadog <=> something else integrations a while ago.

- Quick answer: there's no super easy way to do this right now using a pre-built dashboard you can just turn on.
- If you wanted to build a dashboard for everyone: https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-extras is the repo where they get built. You could build one.
- If you wanted a cheap and easy route: Iterable has an API [here](https://api.iterable.com/api/docs) which you could pull data from to send into Datadog using their Submit Metrics API [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/metrics/#submit-metrics), and these would be charged under the "custom metrics" part of your DDog bill.
- If Segment data is enough, try turning on their dashboard following the instructions [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/segment/) and you'll be good to go!